# How to position text under image column?

Tags: html, css

How do I make it so that where the text is, it is just white space and the text instead goes under the picture? Heres an image of what the code is doing on the site: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAwLN.jpg

Heres my current CSS for the image grid setup: `

```
.column{ float: left; width: 33.3%; padding:5px;} .column img{height: 370px; width:300px}
```

Comment: Attach full html and css code

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried to identify and then fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can make your code like this,

```css
.img-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.img-card img{
  border: solid black 1px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.img-card p{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <div class="img-container">
    <div class="img-card">
      <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/181021/file-338034070-jpg/images/real_world_examples.jpg">
      <p>Message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-card">
      <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/181021/file-338034070-jpg/images/real_world_examples.jpg">
      <p>Message</p>
    </div>
    <div class="img-card">
      <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/181021/file-338034070-jpg/images/real_world_examples.jpg">
       <p>Message</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand what you mean, but if it's about layouts you better learn about `css grid`
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.image > img{
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/181021/file-338034070-jpg/images/real_world_examples.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/181021/file-338034070-jpg/images/real_world_examples.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/181021/file-338034070-jpg/images/real_world_examples.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/181021/file-338034070-jpg/images/real_world_examples.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/181021/file-338034070-jpg/images/real_world_examples.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/181021/file-338034070-jpg/images/real_world_examples.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum molestiae quasi incidunt esse quisquam reiciendis error cum ea quos doloremque.</div>
```